# Some issue about Jenkins Multi-configuration project

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

It return with this error:
[image]
[image]

I have change the cloud setting, "docker host uri tcp://172.17.0.2:2375".

Here is my container hosts:

127.0.0.1   localhost

::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback

fe00::0 ip6-localnet

ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix

ff02::1 ip6-allnodes

ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

172.17.0.2  1b0ab63069bd

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I figure out the answer.

In Windows, by default, the Docker Host URI is `tcp://127.0.0.1:2376`.

In Linux, by default, the Docker Host URI is `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`.